# User-Defined ORDERing in SQL

Tags: order-by

I have just read an [interesting blog article](https://begriffs.com/posts/2018-03-20-user-defined-order.html) regarding User-Defined resultset ordering.

> Some applications, such as todo lists, need to maintain a user-defined
>   order of items. The challenge is that the order is arbitrary and can
>   change when the user rearranges items

An example table could be like so:

```
create table items
(
  itemid int primary key,
  itemdata varchar(200),
  ...
  ...
  userorder ??? 
);
```

With a possible retrieval query of:

```
select * from items order by userorder asc;
```

Are there any approaches that I should consider given I'd like to keep updates to a minimum, updates atomic, and retrieval queries as simple and "performant" as possible?

My initial thought was to use an extra `TIMESTAMP` column, and only update `userorder` and the `timestamp` values for a single row (with the retrieval query using `ORDER`ing by `userorder asc, usertimestamp desc`), but that fails when you need to move a row in between two other rows that have the same value.

No specific database in mind, as i use a broad spectrum myself.

Comment: Can ANY order be defined by the user at any time? If so I can't see any way of doing this other than updating every row on every change, due to the sequential nature of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Intro

Some really old BASIC languages required a Line Numbers for every line of code.

When programming, the line numbers where usually spaced out in multiples of 10.
This allowed you to add more code between lines at a later date.

Your `items` table should follow the same concept.

## Basic algorithm

1. Values for `userorder` start off as multiples of 10 start with 10 for each `userid`
2. Application updates `userorder` as needed
3. You renumber that user's `userorder` using Analytics
4. Values for 'userorder` remain as multiples of 10.
5. `commit` the data changes.

## Re-enumeration code

This is basically what I have used:

```
merge into items a
using (
  select i.itemid
    ,10 * row_number() over (partition by i.userid order by i.userorder)
      as new_userorder
  from items i
  where i.userid=?
) b
on (a.itemid = b.itemid)
when matched then update
  set a.userorder=b.new_userorder
;
```

I'm assuming this table holds everyone's TODO list and each user is identified by `userid`.

This example uses `ROW_NUMBER()` from Oracle.  You'll have to substitute it for whatever RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 5):

> *Are there any approaches that I should consider given I'd like to keep updates to a minimum, updates atomic, and retrieval queries as simple and "performant" as possible?*

I think of this as an esoteric variation of the "True Fractions" approach in that blog post — the advantage being that there is no need to introduce a user-defined type (at least if you are using Postgres).

This works using the natural ordering properties of `varbit` and mapping a sequence of them onto a binary tree such that it is always possible to generate another `varbit` value between any two existing adjacent values:

```
                          _____ 1 ____
                   ______/            \______
              _ 01 _                          11
            _/      \_                    _/      \_
        001            011            101            111
       /   \          /   \          /   \          /   \
    0001   0011    0101   0111    1001   1011    1101    1111
```

> ```
> create table foo(id serial primary key, userorder varbit unique);
>
> create function adj(orig varbit, b varbit) returns varbit language sql as $$
>   select substring(orig for length(orig)-1)
>        ||b
>        ||substring(orig from length(orig));
> $$;
>
> create function f(l varbit, h varbit) returns varbit language plpgsql as $$
>
> begin
>   if l is null and h is null then return B'1'; end if;
>   if l is null then return adj(h,B'0'); end if;
>   if h is null then return adj(l,B'1'); end if;
>   if length(l)>length(h) then return adj(l,B'1'); end if;
>   return adj(h,B'0');
> end;
> $$;
> ```

> ```
> insert into foo(userorder) values(f(null,null));
> select * from foo order by userorder;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | userorder
> -: | :--------
>  1 | 1
> ```

> ```
> insert into foo(userorder) values(f(null,B'1'));
> select * from foo order by userorder;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | userorder
> -: | :--------
>  2 | 01       
>  1 | 1
> ```

> ```
> insert into foo(userorder) values(f(B'01',B'1'));
> select * from foo order by userorder;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | userorder
> -: | :--------
>  2 | 01       
>  3 | 011      
>  1 | 1
> ```

> ```
> insert into foo(userorder)
> values(f(B'01',B'011')),(f(B'011',B'1')),(f(B'1',null));
>
> select * from foo order by userorder;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | userorder
> -: | :--------
>  2 | 01       
>  4 | 0101     
>  3 | 011      
>  5 | 0111     
>  1 | 1        
>  6 | 11
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6c97557c00505a5ecf5f216e49ef0fe1)*

If you initially load a lot of ordered rows, you may want to use some other algorithm for generating the initial `userorder` values as you will hit the worst case for space usage (each row will use one more bit for `userorder` than the row before). You could step through same-length values for a sufficiently large number of bits (eg for 8 values: `B'0001'`, `B'0011'`, `B'0101'`, `B'0111'`, `B'1001'`, `B'1011'`, `B'1101'`, `B'1111'`).